# BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'user' with values ['nickname']. Did you forget to specify values ['page', 'username']?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-login

I am getting the following error when I try to goto index.html on my site. The site was templated from https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins I modified it to take in usernames/passwords and got rid of openid. I went through and replaced nickname in the database with username and somehow it is still referencing it even after I have updated the database. I'm still new to this so please go easy. I searched for how to build url's and can't find anything I'm doing wrong.

```
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'user' with values ['nickname']. Did you forget to specify values ['page', 'username']?
```

Here is most of the code to it, let me know and I'll post anything else relevant.

views.py

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, request, \
    g, jsonify
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from flask_sqlalchemy import get_debug_queries
from flask_babel import gettext
from datetime import datetime
from guess_language import guessLanguage
from app import app, db, lm, babel
from .forms import EditForm, PostForm, SearchForm, RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from .models import User, Post
from .emails import follower_notification
from .translate import microsoft_translate
from config import POSTS_PER_PAGE, MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS, LANGUAGES, \
    DATABASE_QUERY_TIMEOUT


@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))


@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(LANGUAGES.keys())


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
    if g.user.is_authenticated:
        g.user.last_seen = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.add(g.user)
        db.session.commit()
        g.search_form = SearchForm()
    g.locale = get_locale()



@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    for query in get_debug_queries():
        if query.duration >= DATABASE_QUERY_TIMEOUT:
            app.logger.warning(
                "SLOW QUERY: %s\nParameters: %s\nDuration: %fs\nContext: %s\n" %
                (query.statement, query.parameters, query.duration,
                 query.context))
    return response


@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found_error(error):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404


@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    db.session.rollback()
    return render_template('500.html'), 500


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index(page=1):
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        language = guessLanguage(form.post.data)
        if language == 'UNKNOWN' or len(language) > 5:
            language = ''
        post = Post(body=form.post.data, timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                    author=g.user, language=language)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(gettext('Your post is now live!'))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    posts = g.user.followed_posts().paginate(page, POSTS_PER_PAGE, False)
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Home',
                           form=form,
                           posts=posts)


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    print("request.form=", request.form, "form.validate=", form.validate())
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        print("BLANK")
        print(User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first())
        if User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first() == None:
            user = User(username=form.username.data)
            user.hash_password(form.password.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            # make the user follow him/herself
            db.session.add(user.follow(user))
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Thanks for registering')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash('Username already exists')
            return render_template('register.html', form=form)
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form=LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
        user=User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user and user.verify_password(form.password.data):
            if 'remember_me' in session:
                remember_me = session['remember_me']
                session.pop('remember_me', None)
            login_user(user, remember=remember_me)
            flash("Logged in sucessfully.")
            '''eventually update to add security to redirects
            if not is_safe_url(next):
                return flask.abort(400)
            return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('index'))
            '''
            return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('index'))
        flash("Incorrect username or password")
    return render_template('login.html',
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form)
'''
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username).first()
        login_user(user)
        session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
    return render_template('login.html',
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form)
'''

'''
@oid.after_login
def after_login(resp):
    if resp.email is None or resp.email == "":
        flash(gettext('Invalid login. Please try again.'))
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=resp.email).first()
    if user is None:
        username = resp.username
        if username is None or username == "":
            username = resp.email.split('@')[0]
        username = User.make_valid_username(username)
        username = User.make_unique_username(username)
        user = User(username=username, email=resp.email)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        # make the user follow him/herself
        db.session.add(user.follow(user))
        db.session.commit()
    remember_me = False
    if 'remember_me' in session:
        remember_me = session['remember_me']
        session.pop('remember_me', None)
    login_user(user, remember=remember_me)
    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('index'))
'''


@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/user/<username>')
@app.route('/user/<username>/<int:page>')
@login_required
def user(username, page=1):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if user is None:
        flash(gettext('User %(username)s not found.', username=username))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    posts = user.posts.paginate(page, POSTS_PER_PAGE, False)
    return render_template('user.html',
                           user=user,
                           posts=posts,
               title='Your Profile')


@app.route('/mobility', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def mobility():
    return render_template('mobility.html')


@app.route('/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit():
    form = EditForm(g.user.username)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        g.user.username = form.username.data
        g.user.about_me = form.about_me.data
        db.session.add(g.user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(gettext('Your changes have been saved.'))
        return redirect(url_for('edit'))
    elif request.method != "POST":
        form.username.data = g.user.username
        form.about_me.data = g.user.about_me
    return render_template('edit.html', form=form)


@app.route('/follow/<username>')
@login_required
def follow(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if user is None:
        flash('User %s not found.' % username)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if user == g.user:
        flash(gettext('You can\'t follow yourself!'))
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))
    u = g.user.follow(user)
    if u is None:
        flash(gettext('Cannot follow %(username)s.', username=username))
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    flash(gettext('You are now following %(username)s!', username=username))
    follower_notification(user, g.user)
    return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))


@app.route('/unfollow/<username>')
@login_required
def unfollow(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if user is None:
        flash('User %s not found.' % username)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if user == g.user:
        flash(gettext('You can\'t unfollow yourself!'))
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))
    u = g.user.unfollow(user)
    if u is None:
        flash(gettext('Cannot unfollow %(username)s.', username=username))
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    flash(gettext('You have stopped following %(username)s.',
                  username=username))
    return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))


@app.route('/delete/<int:id>')
@login_required
def delete(id):
    post = Post.query.get(id)
    if post is None:
        flash('Post not found.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if post.author.id != g.user.id:
        flash('You cannot delete this post.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your post has been deleted.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def search():
    if not g.search_form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return redirect(url_for('search_results', query=g.search_form.search.data))


@app.route('/search_results/<query>')
@login_required
def search_results(query):
    results = Post.query.whoosh_search(query, MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS).all()
    return render_template('search_results.html',
                           query=query,
                           results=results)


@app.route('/translate', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def translate():
    return jsonify({
        'text': microsoft_translate(
            request.form['text'],
            request.form['sourceLang'],
            request.form['destLang'])})
```

models.py

```
from hashlib import md5
import re
from app import db
from app import app
from config import WHOOSH_ENABLED
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context

import sys
if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    enable_search = False
else:
    enable_search = WHOOSH_ENABLED
    if enable_search:
        import flask_whooshalchemy


followers = db.Table(
    'followers',
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    followed = db.relationship('User',
                               secondary=followers,
                               primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
                               secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
                               backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
                               lazy='dynamic')
    def hash_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash=pwd_context.encrypt(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return pwd_context.verify(password, self.password_hash)

    @staticmethod
    def make_valid_username(username):
        return re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]', '', username)

    @staticmethod
    def make_unique_username(username):
        if User.query.filter_by(username=username).first() is None:
            return username
        version = 2
        while True:
            new_username = username + str(version)
            if User.query.filter_by(username=new_username).first() is None:
                break
            version += 1
        return new_username

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        try:
            return unicode(self.id)  # python 2
        except NameError:
            return str(self.id)  # python 3

    def avatar(self, size):
        return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%s?d=mm&s=%d' % \
            (md5(self.email.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), size)

    def follow(self, user):
        if not self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.append(user)
            return self

    def unfollow(self, user):
        if self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.remove(user)
            return self

    def is_following(self, user):
        return self.followed.filter(
            followers.c.followed_id == user.id).count() > 0

    def followed_posts(self):
        return Post.query.join(
            followers, (followers.c.followed_id == Post.user_id)).filter(
                followers.c.follower_id == self.id).order_by(
                    Post.timestamp.desc())

    def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return '<User %r>' % (self.username)


class Post(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['body']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    language = db.Column(db.String(5))

    def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)

#if enable_search:
#    whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, Post)
```

index.html

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ _('Hi, %(username)s!', username=g.user.username) }}</h1>
    {% include 'flash.html' %}
    <div class="well">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="control-group{% if form.post.errors %} error{% endif %}">
                <label class="control-label" for="post">{{ _('Say something:') }}</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    {{ form.post(size=30, maxlength=140) }}
                    {% for error in form.post.errors %}
                        <span class="help-inline">[{{ error }}]</span><br>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ _('Post!') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% for post in posts.items %}
        {% include 'post.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
    <ul class="pager">
        {% if posts.has_prev %}
        <li class="previous"><a href="{{ url_for('index', page=posts.prev_num) }}">{{ _('Newer posts') }}</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="previous disabled"><a href="#">{{ _('Newer posts') }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if posts.has_next %}
        <li class="next"><a href="{{ url_for('index', page=posts.next_num) }}">{{ _('Older posts') }}</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="next disabled"><a href="#">{{ _('Older posts') }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

post.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td width="70px"><a href="{{ url_for('user', username=post.author.username) }}"><img src="{{ post.author.avatar(70) }}" /></a></td>
        <td>
            {% autoescape false %}
            <p>{{ _('%(username)s said %(when)s:', username='<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url_for('user', username=post.author.username), post.author.username), when=momentjs(post.timestamp).fromNow()) }}</p>
            {% endautoescape %}
            <p><strong><span id="post{{ post.id }}">{{ post.body }}</span></strong></p>
            {% if post.language != None and post.language != '' and post.language != g.locale %}
            <div>
                <span id="translation{{ post.id }}">
                    <a href="javascript:translate('{{ post.language }}', '{{ g.locale }}', '#post{{ post.id }}', '#translation{{ post.id }}', '#loading{{ post.id }}');">{{ _('Translate') }}</a>
                </span>
                <img id="loading{{ post.id }}" style="display: none" src="/static/img/loading.gif">
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if post.author.id == g.user.id %}
            <div><a href="{{ url_for('delete', id = post.id) }}">{{ _('Delete') }}</a></div>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from flask_babel import gettext
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField, TextAreaField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, EqualTo
from .models import User


class LoginForm(Form):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)



class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username=StringField('Username', validators=[Length(min=4, max=25)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(),
        EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')])
    confirm = PasswordField('Repeat Password')
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)


class EditForm(Form):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    about_me = TextAreaField('about_me', validators=[Length(min=0, max=140)])

    def __init__(self, original_username, *args, **kwargs):
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.original_username = original_username

    def validate(self):
        if not Form.validate(self):
            return False
        if self.username.data == self.original_username:
            return True
        if self.username.data != User.make_valid_username(self.username.data):
            self.username.errors.append(gettext(
            'This username has invalid characters. '
            'Please use letters, numbers, dots and underscores only.'))
            return False
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=self.username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            self.username.errors.append(gettext(
                'This username is already in use. '
                'Please choose another one.'))
            return False
        return True


class PostForm(Form):
    post = StringField('post', validators=[DataRequired()])


class SearchForm(Form):
    search = StringField('search', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Here is the full error from the console

```
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'user' with values ['nickname']. Did you forget to specify values ['page', 'username']?
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:30:22] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:30:22] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:30:22] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:30:22] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:30:22] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 * Detected change in '/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/views.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_whooshalchemy.py:18: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sqlalchemy is deprecated, use flask_sqlalchemy instead.
  import flask.ext.sqlalchemy as flask_sqlalchemy
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 196-025-674
/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/views.py:34: FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning: "flask_wtf.Form" has been renamed to "FlaskForm" and will be removed in 1.0.
  g.search_form = SearchForm()
/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/views.py:66: FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning: "flask_wtf.Form" has been renamed to "FlaskForm" and will be removed in 1.0.
  form = PostForm()
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:45:14] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 228, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/views.py", line 81, in index
    posts=posts)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 116, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/templates/index.html", line 2, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/templates/base.html", line 63, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/templates/index.html", line 27, in block "content"
    {% include 'post.html' %}
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/templates/post.html", line 3, in top-level template code
    <td width="70px"><a href="{{ url_for('user', nickname=post.author.nickname) }}"><img src="{{ post.author.avatar(70) }}" /></a></td>
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 333, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1805, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 323, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1768, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'user' with values ['nickname']. Did you forget to specify values ['page', 'username']?
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:45:14] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:45:14] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:45:14] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:45:14] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2017 10:45:15] "GET /index?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The route calls for the variable `username` to be defined, but you're passing a variable called `nickname` in your post.html template.

```
flask.url_for('user', nickname=post.author.nickname)
```

needs to be changed to:

```
flask.url_for('user', username=post.author.nickname)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was looking at an old template in gedit and was editing the wrong code. I was about to go crazy with why i was getting this error even though the code it referenced didn't exist.

Comment: Wish you had left the original template up as it is impossible to follow this thread now as there is no error, it's not possible to see how this was fixed