# Flask-SQLalchemy pagination error, Could not build url for endpoint

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to implement pagination with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Here is what I have done for my route

```
@app.route('/client/<int:page_num>',methods=['POST','GET'])
def client(page_num=None):
    form = ClientForm(request.form)
    if current_user.is_active ==True:
        if current_user.user_role == "super_admin":
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                message=addOrUpdateClient(form, current_user)
                return jsonify(json.dumps(message))
            if (page_num):
                clients = Client.query.paginate(per_page=5, page=page_num, error_out=True)
            else:
                clients = Client.query.paginate(per_page=5, page=1, error_out=True)
            return render_template('client.html/',  user=current_user,form = form,clients= clients)
    else:
        next_page = url_for('login')
        return redirect(next_page)
```

And my template file is

```
      {% if clients %}
         <h4>All client</h4>
         <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="client_table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Client Name</th>
                  <th>Client Short Name</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {% for client in clients.items %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{client.client_name}}</td>
                  <td>{{client.client_code}}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}

              </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
            {% for client in clients.iter_pages(left_edge=3, right_edge=3, left_current=3, right_current=3) %}
        {% if page %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('client',page_num=page) }}">{{page}}</a>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

But when I tried to load I get the following error

`Could not build url for endpoint 'client'. Did you forget to specify values ['page_num']?`

Before adding this pagination , my code were working fine . One more thing to be noted here , is that I didn't even hit '/client' route . I got this error in index page `http://localhost:5000/`

**Edit:**

It seems , there is a problem in my html template , although I am still not sure

I was building url for navigation in my html template like following

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('client') }}">
              <i class="ti-shield menu-icon"></i>
              <span class="menu-title">Client</span>
            </a>
          </li>
```

And the IDE is pointing error at this line.

Comment: `url_for('client')` does not provide the param expected by your route configuration (not the function).

Comment: What shall I do to fix it?

Comment: Pass it a `page_num`.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060207/builderror-could-not-build-url-for-endpoint-user-with-values-nickname-di